# C# OpenFileDialog Why the File Name is adding spaces like this?

Tags: c#

im using the richtextbox to view the .txt file , opening it with toolstrip button

and i made the filename same as lblidstruk.Text , and the label changes if the cell row[0] clicked

why the hell the Filename has a spaces after lblidstruk.Text once it opens..

Image OpenFileDialog

[image]

**Datagridview cell click**

```
int i;
        private void dataGridView2_CellClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            i = e.RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView2.Rows[i];
            lblidstruk.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }
```

**Form Laporan Load**

```
private void laporan_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = "SELECT DISTINCT idStruk,JumlahTerjual,Harga,Tanggal FROM Laporan ";

            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SDA.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
```

**ToolStripButton**

```
private void tbOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            string path = "C:\\faktur";
            // Kode ini akan membuat Open Files teks
            OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
            //rtfReceipt.LoadFile(lblidstruk.Text = Path.GetFileName(openFile.FileName), RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            openFile.InitialDirectory = path;
            openFile.Filter = "text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFile.FileName = String.Format("{0}.txt", lblidstruk.Text);
            if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                rtfReceipt.LoadFile(openFile.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        }
```

Comment: Is not the problem in the source *(`lblidstruk.Text`)*? This is a standard behaviour for databases with fixed length *(adding spaces to values)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix, is ensure `lblidstruk.Text` is Trimmed of white space

```
String.Format("{0}.txt", lblidstruk.Text.Trim());
```

However this problem is probably caused (and should be fixed elsewhere)

Obviously its coming from the DB, because of a fixed length string

[String.Trim Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the
>   current String object.

Comment: Question is : *why the hell the Filename has a spaces after lblidstruk* ? not how to Remove space/fix. Hence it wont answers the question, is it?

Comment: @sujithkarivelil: see my comment for the question. Is this not a default database behaviour?

Comment: @Julo: yes of course, that's why I voted for the comment